# How to use MeasureExpression In SSDT?

Tags: ssas, mdx, sql-server-data-tools

I have sth like this in my fact table :

a dimenstion named **dimType** that can have these values "**FIND** , **LOSE** , **GIFT**"
and a measure named **Count** that has a positive number

I want this measure in SSDT by **SUM** AggregateFunction but with a little change, before aggrigation I want to negetive this **Count** if it's of type **LOSE**
ex :

Type : **FIND**    / Count  :**12**
Type : **LOSE**  / Count  : **5**
Type : **GIFT**   / Count  :  **4**

THEN : SUM(Count) = 12-5+4 = 11

Should I use **MeasureExpression** in Measure Properties ? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the easiest way to do it is SQL:

```
iif(type = 'LOSE',-count,count)
```

If you need it for some reason both positive and negative aggregation you can you use MDX calculations.

Simple one:

```
[Measures].[Count] - ([dimType].[Type].[LOSE],[Measures].[Count]) * 2
```

Universal one:

```
Sum(
    Existing [dimType].[Type].[Type].Members,
    Iif(
        [dimType].[Type].CurrentMember is [dimType].[Type].[LOSE],
        -[Measures].[Count],
        [Measures].[Count]
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) For better test I implemented your Formulas  on [Adventure Works] cube by changing [dimType].[Type] to **[Product].[Category]** (I want **[Bike]** to be negative instead of [LOSE]) and changing  [Measures].[Count] to **[Measures].[Internet Order Quantity]** here's the result [Picture](http://oi65.tinypic.com/2i8jgcy.jpg) as u see in the picture, if I filter category then F1_Simple is not correct when selecting category on rows and F2_sum is not correct when not selecting category on rows

Comment: Heh, try Excel and you will be surprised. :)

Comment: The problem is BIRD browser filter generator. BIRD puts everything in subselect which is incorrect for some sort of calculations (calculations simply don't know what do you have filtered, because of sub queries). Meanwhile, Excel won't allow you to generate subselects, thus prevent you from unexpected results.

Comment: Yup, it should work as expected in any case, however, may appear slow sometimes.